# Is there a way to access 3-year-old tweets using the Tweet ID?

Tags: twitter

I am trying to do research and access pre-curated tweets from 2015 using the Twitter API or another method. I am not sure if it is possible because the tweets are a few years old.

Comment: You will need a premium api to get full search endpoint. Because public API is 7 days back only.

Comment: Thanks, I applied for premium and am on the wait list. Do you have any idea how long it usually takes to get assessed?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can go through this "GET statuses/show/:id". 
For more information visit the twitter API [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id).